# i want to compute the distance between two numpy histogram

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, histogram, distance

i'm creating an image processing program and i want to measure the wasserstein  distance between  two numpy histograms.
the two histogram are created with the function [numpy.histogram](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html)

i tried the wasserstein_distance from the scipy.stats package like this

```
from scipy.stats import wasserstein_distance 
wasserstein_distance(histogram1,histogram2)
```

but it gives me that error

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

the complete code:

first the function that calculate the distance:

```
    def f_dist( histogram1 ,histogram2):
    return wasserstein_distance(histogram1,histogram2)
```

than the function that calculate the mask for the histograme creation:

```
def prepare_mask(polygon, image,value):
"""Returns binary mask based on input polygon presented as list of coordinates of vertices
Params:
    polygon (list) - coordinates of polygon's vertices. Ex: [(x1,y1),(x2,y2),...] or [x1,y1,x2,y2,...]
    image (numpy array) - original image. Will be used to create mask of the same size. Shape (H, W, C).
Output:
    mask (numpy array) - boolean mask. Shape (H, W).
"""
# create an "empty" pre-mask with the same size as original image
width = image.shape[1]
height = image.shape[0]
mask = Image.new('L', (width, height),value )
# Draw your mask based on polygon
ImageDraw.Draw(mask).polygon(polygon, outline=1, fill=abs(value-1))
# Covert to np array
mask = np.array(mask).astype(bool)
return mask
```

than the function that creat the histogram

```
def compute_histogram(mask, image):
"""Returns histogram for image region defined by mask for each channel
Params:
    image (numpy array) - original image. Shape (H, W, C).
    mask (numpy array) - boolean mask. Shape (H, W).
Output:
    list of tuples, each tuple (each channel) contains 2 arrays: first - computed histogram, the second - bins.

"""
# Apply binary mask to your array, you will get array with shape (N, C)
region = image[mask]

hist = np.histogram(region.ravel(), bins=256, range=[0, 255])

return hist
```

and now for the main fnction:

```
points=[(633, 312), (630, 351), (623, 389), (611, 426), (594, 462), (573, 495), (548, 525), (519, 552), (488, 575), (453, 594), (417, 608), (379, 618), (340, 623), (301, 623), (262, 618), (224, 608), (188, 594), (153, 575), (122, 552), (93, 525), (68, 495), (47, 462), (30, 426), (18, 389), (11, 351), (9, 311), (11, 272), (18, 234), (30, 197), (47, 161), (68, 128), (93, 98), (122, 71), (153, 48), (188, 29), (224, 15), (262, 5), (301, 0), (340, 0), (379, 5), (417, 15), (453, 29), (488, 48), (519, 71), (548, 98), (573, 128), (594, 161), (611, 197), (623, 234), (630, 272)]
mask1 = prepare_mask(points, image_gray, 0)
mask2 = prepare_mask(points, image_gray, 1)
histogram1 = compute_histogram(mask1, image_gray)
histogram2 = compute_histogram(mask2, image_gray)
dist=f_dist(histogram1,histogram2)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Are you able to provide a complete example (i.e. all the code required to reproduce your error). Without knowing what's in `histogram1` and 2 it's hard to know why that error is being thrown.

Comment: ok but it will take some time because the code contains a lot of functions so  i nead to choose just the functions that i nead for the distance

Comment: ok i've added the code

Comment: Did you take care that `np.histogram` returns not only the histogram, but a tuple of that plus bin edges? In other words: how about `wasserstein_distance(histogram1[0], histogram2[0])`?

Comment: no i didn't try that ...

Comment: so you are saying that the first row histogram[0] is the real histogram?

Comment: ok it worked .... i'm sorry for wasting your time i was stupid

Comment: Never mind, mistakes happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank to SpghttCd the solution was simple ... i had just to replace

```
wasserstein_distance(histogram1, histogram2)
```

with

```
wasserstein_distance(histogram1[0], histogram2[0])
```

Comment: wasserstein_distance(histogram1[0], histogram2[0]) spits out a number, but it is not the distance between two histograms. It treats frequencies of each bin as a value and then builds the historical distributions from those values and computes the distance. You can either simply pass the values that you create histograms from or pass mid points of bins as values and frequencies as weights to wasserstein_distance() function.